# Any idea on how to plot just true values of Boolean?

Tags: python, boolean

```
sns.countplot(data = accidents_2019, x = "motorbikes", palette="spring")
plt.show ()
```

[image]

How do I plot just True values? I cant even see the true values in my current figure

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.countplot(data =accidents_2019, x = "Day_of_Week", hue = "motorbikes");
plt.title ("accident severity by motorbikes")
plt.show ()
```

[image]

Comment: What are the contents of `accidents_2019`?

Comment: Accidents 2019 contains all recorded accidents in 2019. Am Trying to single out accidents by motorbikes then plot that by number of motorbike accidents by different days of the week.

Comment: I understood that, but how do I know how to figure out if an accident is True or not? You need some pattern to make an algorithm

Comment: I have already worked out if an accident is True or Not I just need to work out how to plot just the True values. At the moment when I try to plot my algorithm it plots both the False and True values. As the False value is much greater that True values, the True values are not even showing in my diagram.